# Rcpp - error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct SEXPREC’

Tags: rcpp

I have two functions below.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector temp(int x, NumericVector vec)
{
  NumericVector ret = pow(vec[seq_len(x) - 1] - 10, 3);

  return(ret);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector temp2(int x, NumericVector vec)
{
  NumericVector top = vec[seq_len(x) - 1];

  NumericVector ret = pow(top - 10, 3);

  return(ret);
}
```

I want to be able to use the function temp, however when I try to compile it I get the error:

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct SEXPREC’`
```

I can make it work by first putting it into a NumericVector variable. How can I modify the function `temp` so that I don't have to use the temporary variable in `temp2`? If I could avoid the variable declaration in `temp` altogether that would be great.

Comment: We welcome patches to extend the template meta programming that make `temp2()` possible so that `temp()` also compiles.  In the meantime, just use the code in `temp2()`.

Comment: Thanks for the response Dirk. Wasn't aware this capability wasn't implemented yet. If I wanted to try and come up with a patch for this for Rcpp what topics should I look for to learn?